# Angular2 form disable submit

Tags: forms, validation, button, angular, recaptcha

I put a recaptcha in a signup form with angular2.
I have a controller to match the recaptcha with a validator required.

```
this.captchaControl = fb.control(false, Validators.required); 
this.userForm = fb.group({
    ...
    captchaControl: this.captchaControl
});
```

And the value is correctly set to true when the user answer it.

```
checkReCaptcha(response){
    console.log(this.userForm.valid);
    this.captcha = response;
    this.captchaControl.updateValue(true);
    console.log(this.userForm.valid);
}
```

The first console log show false, the second print true.

In the submit button, I put the disable function:

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!userForm.valid" class="btn btn-d">Register</button>
```

But the button stay disable.

How can I trigger the button to check again the validity of `userForm`?

**Update**
Here is an example of my problem.
http://plnkr.co/edit/Rwy6Oc5JEEm7yIJYnxJX?p=preview

When you complete the form, the red button stay disabled even though the form is valid. If you touch any other input form (or the other submit button), the disabled button is updated and becomes available, but it I would expect it to become available when all inputs are defined...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a change detection issue caused by code running outside of Angulars zone.

inject `ApplicationRef` and call tick()` after the value was changed

```
import {ApplicationRef} from 'angular2/core';

constructor(private appRef:ApplicationRef){} 

checkReCaptcha(response){
    console.log(this.userForm.valid);
    this.captcha = response;
    this.captchaControl.updateValue(true);
    this.appRef.tick();
    console.log(this.userForm.valid);
}
```

This makes Angular aware that change detection needs to be done.

http://plnkr.co/edit/nYKqtXaaDl69eeL35GTL?p=info

Interestingly no other way of invoking change detection actually worked.

- setTimeout(...)
- ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck()
- zone.run(...)

didn't cause a new change detection to run. At least when I changed the binding `{{userForm.valid}}` to `{{isUserFormValid()}}`, `isUserFormValid()` wasn't called.

Only `this.appRef.tick()` made Angular2 reevaluate the binding.

Comment: I tried but probably I miss something.
I add the change strategy

`@Component({
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})`

and I past the lines that you put but the result look to be the same.
What is the angular zone ?

Comment: See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/NgZone-class.html, http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/01/zones-in-angular-2.html, http://victorsavkin.com/post/118372404541/the-core-concepts-of-angular-2. Zone is a wrapper Angular runs in which patches some APIs to get notified when events are fired or async operations are finished. This is when Angular runs change detection. I'll look into the issue.

Comment: Can you create a Plunker that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Here is the plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/xs3MG8FcH8DlkTtEfYJR?p=preview 
But I am a bit disapointed because plunker make window undefined and so the script cannot bind the callback for recaptcha...

Comment: `checkReCaptcha` wasn't called in the Plunker because of an exception. I changed `window['checkReCaptch'] = () => {
            this.checkReCaptch();
        }`.  Besides that it seems to work, even without the changes I suggested above. http://plnkr.co/edit/SY0gv8Mt80BihxGNMnm7?p=preview

Comment: Great, de callback is called. But I don't see the red button becaming available with or without your proposition when you complete de form (user, password and captcha).
Form is valid but button stay disabled.
(I add small string in print to show validity)
http://plnkr.co/edit/Rwy6Oc5JEEm7yIJYnxJX?p=preview

Comment: Wow, that caused some headaches. `setTimeout(...)`, `appRef.tick(...)`, `zone.run(...)` - none caused a change detection cycle. `ApplicationRef.tick()` did the trick tough. http://plnkr.co/edit/nYKqtXaaDl69eeL35GTL?p=info I changed a few other things while experimenting but I guess these changes are redundant.